# Why isnt my python app converting into an executable file?

Tags: python, command, exe

Im trying to make my python app into an exe using this command:

`pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon="02d@2x.png" Programmieren\WetterApp.py`

I get this Error:

```
line 234, in CopyIcons except win32api.error as W32E:
AttributeError: module 'win32ctypes.pywin32.win32api' has no attribute 'error'
```

Anyone knows what the problem could be? Should have to work out of my perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me when I tried these things.

```
Try using .ico file for the app icon
Try changing the directory of that .ico file to your script directory and run it again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your icon's extention should be `.ico`, convert your `png` to `ico` for it to work.